# Using graph symmetries to speed up subgraph enumeration

Tags: graphs, optimization, search-algorithms, enumeration, group-theory

I have an undirected graph $G$. It has some symmetries in the sense that I know it's automorphism group $\text{Aut}(G)$. I am searching for a specific subgraph defined by some constraints $\phi$ and optimization criterion $f$, i.e. I am solving a problem in the form:
$\max_{G'\subseteq G \land \phi(G')} f(G').$ The subgraphs are generated by only deleting edges and keeping all the vertices.

However, I am only interested in non-symmetric subgraphs and I am want to use the symmetry information to speed up the search. Formally, there is an equivalence relation on the subgraphs: $G_1 \equiv G_2 \iff \exists T\in \text{Aut}(G).  T(G_1) = G_2$ for any subgraphs $G_1 \subseteq G, G_2 \subseteq G$. Now when enumerating the subgraphs to check the constraints and criteria I want to only consider one representative of each equivalence class because I know that in my case it will always hold that $G_1 \equiv G_2 \implies (f(G_1) = f(G_2) \land (\phi(G_1) \iff \phi(G_2)))$. Ideally, this should allow to speed up the whole process by up to the factor $|\text{Aut}(G)|$. We can assume that computing $T(G')$ is asymptotically faster than computing both $\phi(G')$ and $f(G')$.

Is there an intelligent way to approcach this eliminating the symmetries without much computational overhead? I am not sure how to meaningfully define a "canonical subgraph form" for which there would be exactly one representative in each equivalence class, which could lead to a solution. However, I am aware this may be too closely related to the subgraph isomorphism problem, rendering this approach possibly not viable. Any ideas?